# PHP - one curl function returning 404 while the other one is working fine

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-404

I've got a problem with my PHP project. This part of code is not working - when I try to connect to this url it just gives me 404 error (echo $pg; is there just for test purposes).

```
$url='http://myanimelist.net/anime/110/Chuuka_Ichiban';
$ch = curl_init();
$found=0;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; Edition Campaign 21) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__file__) . '/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__file__) . '/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
$pg = curl_get_page($ch);
while (strpos($pg, 'getSessionCookies') !== false)
{
    $pg = curl_get_page($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

echo $pg;
```

The funny thing is that a function just a few lines above this one looks almost the same (duh, I copied it and modified it) and it's working. Same code, same website. Here is the working one:

```
$baseurl=$url.$i;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; Edition Campaign 21) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.14');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__file__) . '/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__file__) . '/cookies.txt');
    $pg = curl_get_page($ch);
    while (strpos($pg, 'getSessionCookies') !== false)
    {
        $pg = curl_get_page($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Could you please help me fix this? I'm trying to finish this webiste as fast as possible. Thanks.

Comment: In the second function your are not using the same url as you are appending a variable to it: `$baseurl=$url.$i;`

Comment: urls are fine, the 2nd code is just an example that the same curl settings worked before.

Comment: Still nothing. I added this line hoping it will fix the problem.